# Inner dimensions of Anchor Hocking glass measuring cups

Tags: equipment, measurements

Hi especially for those who already have the Anchor Hocking glass measuring cups. I wonder what are the inner dimensions (diameter) and height of the Anchor Hocking glass measuring cups (250 ml and 500 ml). I saw several contradicting dimension measurements all over the Internet so I ask this question. Thanks.

Comment: What practical problem would this solve? They're truncated cones, so the diameter changes all the way up.

Comment: I just wanna know the inner upper diameter of the, at least, 1 cup sized Anchor Hocking glass measuring cup before buying one.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor Hocking has been making glass measuring cups for 50 years (possibly as long as 70).  During that time, they have had multiple different designs for their glass measuring cups, some taller and narrower, some wider and shorter.  Even within the last 5 years they've changed the design slightly (taller spouts).

As such, unless you're specifically asking about the 2021 measuring cup model, you're going to get a variety of different measurements.

Comment: I'm talking about I think it is the new one with red letters on it. Any idea?